# How to remove zoom view (that opens in new window) of product image in magento?

Tags: magento

How can I remove the zoom view (that opens in a new window) of a product image in Magento?

When I click on the main product picture it opens the original image. How do I disable this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You could edit this file, or copy it to your current theme and make your edits there: `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml`.

You will see the zoom control gets added like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
        product_zoom = new Product.Zoom('image', 'track', 'handle', 'zoom_in', 'zoom_out', 'track_hint');
    });
//]]>
</script>
```

So it would be simple enough to just comment out that observer and the zoom control buttons.